# Equivalent jQuery function of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, text, editor

**Which would be the equivalent jQuery function to this javascript function?** This is in the context of a text editor based on an iframe (with id='editor') and a textarea (with id='text').

```
function edit(){
edition = document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow;
HTMLcontent = edition.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
HTMLcontent.innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').value;
}
```

Comment: $('#editor #text').html(); or $('#editor').find('#text').html();

Comment: jQuery being javascript, you can use it as is!

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery the code would be like this:

```
bodyIframe = $("#editor").contents().find("body")[0];
bodyIframe.html($("#text").val());
```

Comment: in your case - htmlObj is a Native DOM Element and not a jQuery object - therefore it doesn't have the `.html()` method - and you're missing a closing parenthese

Comment: htmlObj is just a name dude

Comment: then what's this? `htmlObj = $("#editor").contents().find("body")[0];`

Comment: `$("#editor").contents().find("body")` == jQuery object  and `$("#editor").contents().find("body")[0]` == DOM Element

Comment: Now is cool :P, we have the body inside the iframe and we set the html, I've change the name of the body for you to stay happy

Comment: DOM Element's have no .html() method :/

Comment: Now I understand your point, and probably we don't have jquery inside de iframe, then it should be like this:
   ` bodyIframe.innerHTML = $("#text").val();`
Thanks, why this example works?
[link](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)